# Fundapter list view filtering error

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a search function in the list view and I'm using `Fundapter` and not normal `Adapter`. However when I try to type something into the edit text, I get:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

This is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);

    final ArrayList<Participants> participants = new ArrayList<>();

    //then i hardcoded the participants data...

    //participants.add(p1);

    BindDictionary<Participants> dictionary = new BindDictionary<>();
    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Participants>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Participants participants, int position) {
            return participants.getName();
        }
    });

    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvCompany, new StringExtractor<Participants>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Participants participants, int position) {
            return participants.getCompanyName();
        }
    });

    dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvNRIC, new StringExtractor<Participants>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Participants participants, int position) {
            return participants.getNRIC();
        }
    });


    final FunDapter adapter = new FunDapter(ViewFragment.this.getActivity(), participants, R.layout.participants_layout, dictionary);

    ListView lvParticipants = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvParticipants);
    lvParticipants.setAdapter(adapter);
    etSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    lvParticipants.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Participants selectedParticipants = participants.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(ViewFragment.this.getActivity(), selectedParticipants.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

Comment: What error occurs?

Comment: the app just stops and couldn't run at all

Comment: post your error log pls

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `onTextChnaged()`, you are doing your operation in `beforeTextChnaged()`... look into it.

Comment: I changed to onTextChanged() however the app still stops. And I'm not really sure why. I'm new to Android studio.

Comment: post the logcat ..whats the exception ??

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

Comment: either your data set in adapter is null or you are adding Participants a custom data type but filtering based on CharSequence ?

Comment: I was able to display all Participants data(I used Array). But now I just want to filter based on what I type in the edit text. Not sure if the codes for that is correct as I'm new to android studio